# Display Catalog Info on page

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, table

Is it possible to display the Magento product catalog (just a select few columns) on a page on my company site? My company's Magento install is integrated with our ERP system so it shows real-time inventory qty's. I'd like to do this to allow  the sales team a quick and convenient way to sort different product categories and see availability. I'm running 1.9.2.4

Any push in the right direction would be great!

Comment: you can used diffrent magento Rest API, to fetch data and show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,It is possible to display catalog products,order,inventory and much more at third party website. Just you need to use magento API.
You may explore the product API here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/Products/products.html